# Why are my Bootstrap 3 styles & JS not working in IE versions before 10?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a prototype application which you can see here: http://bit.ly/1zVwoo4

The site works fine in Safari, Chrome, Firefox etc.. however in versions of IE before 10, the layout looks terrible, none of the JavaScript works & none of my custom CSS is applied.

Just wondering if their is a known Bootstrap 3 / IE 8 & 9 issue?

I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge, IE < 10 does not use ecma script 5 which would break bootstrap and later JQuery versions. There are shims you can put in your code to try to work around it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with IE 8 and 9. Bootstrap lists them as being supported, but there are a number of caveats with versions earlier than 10.

They have a fairly good rundown of some of the known issues with versions of IE prior to 10 on the Getting Started section of the official site, along with other known issues for other browsers. Definitely good to read up on and be aware of.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9